# Seek method for javafx MediaPlayer does not seek correctly for 1.5 hr+ long audio files

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I recently fixed a bug where the javafx MediaPlayer would break whenever I disconnected my bluetooth headphones. I fixed that by doing this.

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnError( () -> {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            System.out.println(durationBackup.toMillis());
            mediaPlayer.setOnPlaying(() ->{
                mediaPlayer.seek(durationBackup);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPlaying(null);
            });
            mediaPlayer.play();
    });
```

durationBackup is just a backup of the duration before the MediaPlayer crashed. The above code works for a short 5 minute long mp3 file, the newly created MediaPlayer will correctly seek to the durationBackup. However, I then decided to test this code with a 1.5 hour long mp3 file, when tested, the newly created MediaPlayer failed to seek to the durationBackup. Instead, the MediaPlayer object created began to play from the start rather than the desired durationBackup.

After further testing, it seems that the seek method is failing since when I tried to seek 7 seconds from the start of the 1.5 hour long mp3 file, the MediaPlayer instead played from the start. When I used the seek method to seek 7 seconds from the start of the 5 minute long file, the MediaPlayer started playing 7 seconds from the start. I suspect this has to do with the size of the mp3 files, however I cannot seem to find a fix for this. Not only does `seek(Duration.seconds(7))` not work with the 1.5 hour long mp3 file, `setStartTime(Duration.seconds(7))` also does not work with 1.5 hour long mp3 file.

If anyone can help me fix this problem that would be great. There's a mini reproducible example below.

## SevenSecondSeekClass

```
package apprunner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SevenSecondSeekClass extends Application {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        launch(args);

    }

    public InvalidationListener il = new InvalidationListener() {
        public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
            //Here we just print the current time of the song
            System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toSeconds() + " seconds");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("My");
        Button button0 = new Button("Play 7 seconds from start of 5min Song");
        Button button1 = new Button("Play 7 seconds from start of 1hr Song");
        StackPane layout = new StackPane(new VBox(button0, button1));
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 200, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.show();
        File file0 = new File("C:\\Users\\John Doe\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\YourLieInAprilTest\\5minsong.mp3");
        String path0 = file0.toURI().toASCIIString();
        Media media0 = new Media(path0);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media0);
        button0.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event arg0) {
                createNewPlayer(media0);
            }
        });

        File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\John Doe\\downloadedMusic\\1andHalfHourSong.mp3");
        String path1 = file1.toURI().toASCIIString();
        Media media1 = new Media(path1);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media1);
        button1.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event arg0) {
                createNewPlayer(media1);
            }
        });
    }

    public void createNewPlayer(Media media) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().removeListener(il);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPlaying(() -> {
            mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(7));
            System.out.println("Trying to seek to 7 seconds from start of song");
            mediaPlayer.setOnPlaying(null);
        });
        mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(il);//This will help us print the current time of the song
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

If you're wondering why I'm using .seek at the start of the MediaPlayer rather than just using .setStartTime() it's because .setStartTime() would change the values for .getTotalDuration and wouldn't allow be to go to durations less than the start time set. I need those aspects to be available in my program to maintain a usable UI. Also .setStartTime() isn't working with the 1.5 hour long mp3 file either.

## Additional Info

`Link to the 5 minute long Mp3 file I used to test. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CvAafbMviQ7nvKyojnem9GK73LJsD6MJ/view?usp=sharing`

`Link to the 1.5 hour long mp3 file I used to test. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KggQct1VnY18m0_4Wik5pfP4RN8-HbUT/view?usp=sharing`

`I am using JDK 11 and Javafx 17.0.2`

`System Type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor`

`JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.4+11) (build 11.0.4+11)`

`Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.4+11, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)`

`Windows Edition: Windows 10 Home`

Comment: I have just tried to test your case. An interesting thing is that if you seek in long record starting from `61 second` - it moves to this position correctly; if you seek less then `61 seconds` - it moves the wrong position: in my case it was: 56 pos for 60 sec; 53 for 59 sec; 50 for 58 sec... and so on.

Comment: Besides there is still not resolved bug with similar issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151164

Comment: @Alex so there are no workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could fix my problem by converting my mp3 files into m4a files instead. The seeking issue no longer occurs with m4a files.